# How to find an instance in an ndb repeated structured property

Tags: google-app-engine, data-structures, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

When I have a NDB repeated property, i have to iterate over the list to find the property I am looking for. When I look in the datastore, every property of the structured property is a list. I thought I could use the Python list index method, but this does not work.

So is there an easy way to find the structured property instance I need.

```
class Instance(ndb.Model)
    instance_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    instance_data = ndb.TextProperty()

class Example(ndb.Model):
    instances = ndb.StructuredProperty(Instance, repeated = True)
```

I tried:

```
instance_id = 'thisone'
index = entity.instances.instance_id.index(instance_id)
data =  entity.instances.instance_data[index]
```

But I had to :

```
instance_id = 'thisone'
for each in entity.instances :
    if each.instance_id = instance_id :
        instance_data = each.instance_data
        break
```

Comment: Do you have the "Example" instance already loaded and you just need to find one of the associated repeated instances within the structured property OR do you need to load an instance by id independent of the parent?

Comment: entity.instances is already loaded.

Answer (score 2):

So here's the problem - entity.instances is a python list, as per [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured). What you are trying to do is more like a dict. There is a feature request that Guido turned down in the Google Group that seems to be the same thing as what you are asking: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/appengine-ndb-discuss/Kj7Ymhr5hlE/discussion

The entity.instances[0] returns the first instance in that list. All other List operations seem to work as well. But you are trying to effectively query that list.

If you already know what the ID is and your lists are large, you could always set that ID as the key and make a call to the datastore to get just that instance. When you create the instance do something like this:

```
new_instance = Instance(id=instance_id, instance_data=some_data)
```

and then load it like this:

```
existing_instance = Instance.get_by_id(instance_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I will follow the feature request. I create a new instance as you showed. After loading the instance I create  instance dict, which I use as an index to update instances.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following that. I thought you needed to get a specific instance.

Comment: Using your get_by_id I get an instance of the instance Instance(ndb.Model), which is not part of the stuctured property. But this model is also configured as a template for the structured propert, but with the get_by_id it can also been seen as a seperate model, if it contains data.